# jQuery dialog won't stop re-opening

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

Problem with field validation and two jQueryUI dialogs.

There is a registration form in the first jQUI dialog.

Field validation on the username field using AJAX. If field fails validation (already exists), PHP file returns a number > zero and an error message is displayed in *a second jQueryUI dialog*.

However, when user closes 2nd dialog, it immediately re-opens, forever.

Any thoughts?

```
$("#c_username").blur(function() {
    var uu = ($(this).val()).toLowerCase();
    $(this).val(uu); //in case user did not input as all lowercase
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'ajax/ax_all_ajax_fns.php',
        data:'request=does_username_already_exist&username=' + uu,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data != 0) {
                $('#alert').html('Username <span style="font-weight:bold;color:darkgreen;">' +uu+ '</span> already exists. Please enter another.');
                $('#alert').dialog({
                    title: 'Username already exists:',
                    width: 400,
                    close: function() {
                        $(this).dialog('destroy');
                    }
                });
                $("#c_username").addClass('field_invalid').focus();
            }else{
                alert("Username is okay");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#c_username").addClass('field_invalid').focus();` focuses the input behind the dialog. When you click the close button on the dialog, the input's blur event is raised again, causing another ajax call, and another dialog to be opened.

Try moving the `focus()` call to the `close` callback on the dialog. You could also try displaying the message in a span next to the input instead of in a dialog so focus issues can't happen.